# Factorising out repeating data and replacing it with an integer key

Tags: performance, database-design, disk-space

I have noticed in my SQLite database that some tables contain columns where many rows usually repeat the same data.

**Transaction**

| key | from_account_key | to_account_key | timestamp | amount | data_type | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 20 | 40 | 1608320428 | 8 | "BUY" | {blob 1} |
| 201 | 20 | 40 | 1608320429 | 20 | "BUY" | {blob 1} |
| 202 | 20 | 40 | 1608320429 | 20 | "BUY" | {blob 1} |
| 203 | 20 | 40 | 1608320430 | 10 | "BUY" | {blob 1} |
| 204 | 20 | 3 | 1608320434 | 10 | "TRANSFER" | {blob 2} |
| 205 | 20 | 3 | 1608320440 | 20 | "TRANSFER" | {blob 2} |
| 206 | 20 | 3 | 1608320480 | 10 | "TRANSFER" | {blob 2} |
| 207 | 26 | 40 | 1608320510 | 20 | "SELL" | {blob 1} |
| 208 | 40 | 26 | 1608320530 | 20 | "REFUND" | {blob 3} |
| 209 | 20 | 40 | 1608320533 | 26 | "BUY" | {blob 4} |

For example here in this table of transactions you can see that the sender account often sends to the same recipient account, thus there are many repeating cases of `( from_account_key, to_account_key )`. You can also see that `( data_type )` and `( data )` have identical values in many rows as well.

My idea is to factorise these repeating non-single-integer columns into their own tables and then reference them by an integer key, so the repeating values can be reused. (Doing this to this table would result in the tables `Transaction ( key, transaction_accounts_key, timestamp, amount, data_type_key, data_key )` , `TransactionAccounts`, `DataType` and `Data`).

Upsides of this is less repeating data, leading to a smaller database. Downsides are that upserts are more difficult since there are more tables and more logic is required, queries become more complex, and most of all that more joins are required to retrieve the original columns.

So my question is, how far should I go with this? Is there tradeoff between performance and space here?

What I know is that the `( data )` blobs may be relatively big, but repeat many times, so I would definitely put them in their own table and refer to them by an integer key. I would also do this with `( data_type )` because strings may take up relatively much space. But to me this seems a bit overkill for 2 integers `( from_account_key, to_account_key )`, so where do you draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question with more information about the specific database management system you're using as that will affect the applicable answers.

For example, Microsoft SQL Server offers Page and Row level compression out of the box, so your redundant values above would be compressed anyway and your efforts to reduce the database size will be moot.

Amazon Redshift is a columnar OLAP based database management system, so you would likely find even greater compression up-and-down the columns of your tables that housed the example data in your question. (Or a `clustered column store index` in Microsoft SQL Server would also result in a similar outcome.)

Basically the main benefit you would get from replacing your redundant values with an integer foreign key is potentially better `Table normalization` and effectively easier maintainability. The improved maintainability would only be applicable if there was a need to change one of those values and have it update every reference in your `Transaction` table. E.g. if the `to_account_key` of 40 needed to be changed to 90 after the fact. (Though based on your column names having the word "key" in them, I would assume that isn't a realistic use case. One example where this kind of normalization makes sense to do is an enums table.)

Comment: I would hope no one would issue updates against a transaction table with dollar amounts.  And integer replacement <> normalization.

Comment: @bbaird Assuming the fields he's referring to are qualitative (dimensions as opposed to facts) then refactoring them out into their own table to be managed, and replacing their references with their Foreign Key value in his "Transactions" table would be normalization. But I doubt that is the case based on his column names. And I agree, I wouldn't expect the data of a Transactions table to be mutable normally.

Answer (score 0):

Any decisions with respect to keys/tables should keep a few things in mind:

1. Keys are elements of the data that determine uniqueness and relationships between entities
2. We cannot use a system generated value (id) without another key to maintain uniqueness/referential integrity - otherwise it's nothing better than the row number in an Excel spreadsheet
3. As a corollary to 2., any use of a system generated value to act as a key requires another index, which itself has overhead that may be greater than whatever storage savings you get taking 10 bytes down to 4 bytes
4. Data elements repeated across rows <> repeated/duplicated data if the database is properly normalized. If I have AccountNumber on multiple rows in a transaction table, it is not duplicated, it is an element that describes which Account the transaction applies to.
5. The number of tables contained in the database is determined primarily by the data model, an arbitrary "more tables = bad" or "fewer tables = good" misses the point
   Our implementation of the data model should focus primarily on maintaining a consistent picture of the data at a given point in time, not how much space the tables will consume

So regarding your example, I will make the following observations:

1. `key` is just a row identifier, does not provide a way to access the data directly, and is pretty much useless in this context as the actual primary key would be `(from_account_key,timestamp)` as each change of account balance should be atomic<sup>1</sup>.
2. Integer values to define an Account may or may not be the best idea if there is a readily available "Account Number" or other existing data element that is unique and relatively compact.  Otherwise we always need to read `Account` to get the "key" before accessing the `Transaction`.
3. `data_type` doesn't seem like a correct description for something that looks closer to a transaction type. This also looks like a good opportunity to replace the values with a shortened version (controlled through a reference table) that is easily read but also more compact, such as "B" for Buy, "T" for transfer, and so on.
4. SQLite is bad for a lot of reasons (primarily letting you insert anything into any column) and if you're actually processing payments/handling money (and not just storing the data for analysis/reporting) it's probably a good idea to switch to a more robust RDBMS.

I've seen a lot of databases try to get too fancy with trying to save space, and the end result usually is whatever space is saved gets used up by additional indexes, which take space and result in more joins and reads to return the same amount of data. Model the data faithfully, then look to narrow wide keys.

<sup>1</sup> If you need to convince yourself of this, if the starting balance is 50 dollars and two transactions each for 50 dollars are allowed to post at the same time, you will have a negative balance.